# How to avoid saturation in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I run my app both in WebAsm and Server mode (once a time), and when adding cancelling requests, I was surprised there is big difference between those two modes.

As for UI, I have simple page with two buttons, send request and cancel request. In WebAsm it works as expected no matter if the request is CPU intense or not, in Blazor Server mode once the "heavy" request is sent, the click on the button is not even registered, because in this mode all resources go apparently to processing the request.

The handling request on the backend side can be simplified to this logic:

```
while (true) // do some loop
{
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // throw when token is canceled
  Logger.LogInformation("Running"); // there is logging
  await ValueTask.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false); // and there is some async work
}
```

Backend is running and logging, but because it is intense task it has impact on frontend (again, only in Blazor Server).

The workaround I found is to run handlers of the request with explicit wrapping of `Task.Run` with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option.

This "separates" load on frontend and backend enough, so clicks from Blazor UI can be registered, and cancelling can be called.

Is there some systematic/global option to tell Blazor Server "please, keep backend and frontend more separated, so frontend could breathe"?

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see a little more code detail.  NET 8 offers some new client/server "hybrid" modes that you might find worth exploring.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, this is the code I am using, because I was looking for the reason of the difference, so simplification was a must. The code, UI, backend, etc. starts here: https://codeberg.org/macias/lala/src/branch/blazor/app/Lala.WebElements/Pages/Dummy4Page.razor The only important buttons there are calling "freezer" and canceling it. Thank you for pointing for new modes, however I would like to fine-tune Server mode, not ditch it entirely :-).